# Repository bean cannot be found (No idea why)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to run my application and I'm receiving this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.danielturato.product.services.ProductServiceImpl required 
a bean of type 'com.danielturato.product.persistence.ProductRepository' that could not be 
found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.danielturato.product.persistence.ProductRepository' in 
your configuration.
```

I have no idea why this is occurring. I've tried to look at past solutions where its said to use the @EnableMongoRepository to point to the correct package however I have tried this and it doesn't work. I've also tried adding the @Repository annotation above my repository (even though its not needed) and it doesn't work still. Here is my code for my repository, application & where the repository is failing to be injected.

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.danielturato")
public class ProductServiceApplication {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductServiceApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Repository:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<ProductEntity, String> {
    Mono<ProductEntity> findByProductId(int productId);
}
```

ProductServiceImpl:

```
@RestController
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductServiceImpl.class);

    private final ServiceUtil serviceUtil;

    private final ProductRepository repository;

    private final ProductMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    public ProductServiceImpl(ProductRepository repository, ProductMapper mapper, ServiceUtil serviceUtil) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.serviceUtil = serviceUtil;
    }
```

Pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.danielturato</groupId>
    <artifactId>product-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>product-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.Beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.danielturato</groupId>
            <artifactId>api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.danielturato</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.0.Beta2</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If anyone can suggest for me anything to try or would like me to put more info here please let me know.

Comment: Add `@Repository` annotation in `ProductRepository` interface

Comment: I've tried this, still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace you have included in your question does point to the ProductRepository not being available for autowiring and as a previous comment has pointed out this is because you are missing the @Repository annotation from your repository.

Another reason is if your repository cannot find a matching entity. This might be for example if the Id is the wrong type or is missing the @Id annotation, if the entity doesn't have either @Entity/@Document or if it is missing an all args constructor. Plus in your case you have added a findByProductId() method so your entity will need a productId field too.

I would also remove the @ComponentScan annoatation from your application class as this is included by default in @SpringBootApplication unless you are intentionally pointing it at a different class path.

If this still fails as you have mentioned in your comments is it failing for the same reason or is there a different error now related to ProductMapper or ServiceUtil?

Comment: Thank you for the help but the annotations wasn't the issue. The issue was in fact that I was using the spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb dependancy when it should of been the spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive dependancy .

Comment: @Daniel could you share your code with me? I am using psql but I got same error.